# Adopted most of the .htaccess answers for removing .html extension but still no change

Tags: .htaccess

I'm attempting to remove the .html extension from my [website's](http://kadeem.london) child pages;  [papers.html](http://kadeem.london/papers.html). When I click these pages I would like them to be displayed without the .html.

This is how my .htaccess looks at this moment in time. Full of answers that should solve my problem. To give you some background, I'm developing the website from scratch and using filezilla as my FTP solution along with dreamhost as my hosting solution. I've placed .htaccess in the same folder as the index.html folder.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301] 
######################################################################
RewriteRule /(.+)(\.html)$ /$1 [R=301,L] 
######################################################################
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{http://www.proofers.co.uk/new} !(\.[^./]+)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) /$1.html [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^.]+)\.html\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ http://www.proofers.co.uk/new/$1 [R=301,L]
######################################################################
#Section 1
RewriteEngine On
IndexIgnore *
Options +FollowSymLinks -Multiviews -Indexes
######################################################################
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]

# Protect .htaccess
<Files .htaccess>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: Can you start by explaining in more detail what you are trying to do, what pages/URLs you have and what behaviour they are giving you right now?

Comment: Sure, I'll update the question.

Comment: your engine is already on. you don't need to keep doing `rewriteengine on`. it doesn't get "more on".

Comment: Ok thankyou, I understand that now.

Comment: What happens at the moment when you visit /papers?

Comment: The url displays with the url extention .html.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.html[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]
```

For all the html pages. Ask if it's only for one directory...